# Construct set of basis vectors with most zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have a set of basis vectors that describes a linear subspace.  The following is an example of three 16-dimensional vectors:

$$\quad\quad\!\!
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
 1 & -4 & \phantom{-}1 & 1 & \phantom{-}2 & 0 & 2 & -2 & \phantom{-}0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -4 & 1 & 1 & 3 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -4 & 2 & 1 & 2 & -2 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**I want to construct an equivalent basis that has the most possible zeros.**  For example, the above set has 19 zeros.  The following equivalent set has 25 zeros, but I don't know if I can get even more:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
b_1 - b_3 \\
b_1 - b_2 \\
b_3
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -4 & 2 & 1 & 2 & -2 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Are there standard methods to solve this problem?

---

Here's the matrix in machine readable form if anyone feels like experimenting.

```
1   -4  1   1   2    0  2   -2  0   -2  0    0  0   1   0   0
1   -4  1   1   3   -1  1   -1  0   -1  0   -1  1   0   0   0
1   -4  2   1   2   -2  1   -2  1    0  0    0  0   0   0   0
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this turns out to be NP-complete. Finding a solution to a linear system with the minimum number of nonzero entries is NP-complete, according to Garey & Johnson (page 246 of their book).

Comment: @Gerry Do you mean "MP5" in the book?  Thanks for the comment.  That means that it wasn't such a bad thing to come up with my solution using brute-force/heuristics.  I'm relatively confident that there isn't a better solution for this particular case, but I wasn't sure if there was a general methods to deal with these kinds of problems.